# Using Kamon how can I create a UserMetric with "." in the metric name?

Tags: java, scala, akka, statsd, akka-monitoring

I've managed to get the UserMetric extension working in my Java application to send my own stats to a statsd backend but at present the `metric-name-normalization-strategy` overrides my use of "." in the key names and replaces it with "_". I understand why it does this due to the integration with Akka but I don't want this to apply for my own UserMetrics where the "." is important for creating buckets of stats.

Is it possible to use an alternative `metric-name-normalization-strategy` for my user metrics rather than the one used for Akka metrics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the FQCN of your own implementation of `kamon.statsd.MetricKeyGenerator` in the configuration file [1]. Probably you might want to extend the default one [2] and add some special conditions for normalizing user metrics.

[1] https://github.com/kamon-io/Kamon/blob/v0.3.5/kamon-statsd/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L35

[2] https://github.com/kamon-io/Kamon/blob/v0.3.5/kamon-statsd/src/main/scala/kamon/statsd/SimpleMetricKeyGenerator.scala#L13

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kamon-user/6Jt_vcKrrbI